# How to make Doctrine 1.2 run Versionable Behavior when update on some fields?

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony-1.4, versioning

My CMS need to implement Revision control for every Post. With Symfony 1.4 and doctrine 1.2.4, I found solution [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine1/en/latest/en/manual/behaviors.html#versionable) for keep history changes of Post table. When Post was updated, Doctrine make a copy in PostVersion table. It's great for Revision control, but I have big problem!

When Post shows to frontend user, it update column "total_view", and Versionable Behavior will run too. What happen when 10.000 user read that post? I will have 10.000 record in PostVersion table. Oh no!!!

How to make Doctrine 1.2 run Versionable Behavior when update on some fields? maybe "title", "content", and not "total_view", "total_like"...

Answer (score 1):

There's `excludeFields` option:

```
Post:
  actAs:
    Versionable:
      excludeFields: [ total_view ]
```

Comment: These line shorten PostVersion table, helps us exclude fields we don't want to log. But went call save(), Versionable Behavior still log one record to PostVersion. So sad :(

Comment: I think it would work to set your own `listener` in which you need to override `preUpdate` method. In it save `$version` only if there are changed fields of `$record` that are not in `$this->_auditLog->getOption('excludeFields')`